# nodejs configuration httpd.conf

Tags: node.js, configuration

I'm used to apache and putting configuration items in httpd.conf

Where do these types of configurations go in a node environment.  For example, I want to make sure that only GET, POST, and PUT are accepted and Head and Trace are not accepted.  Where does a config like that go?

Additional things like Cache-Control and limiting request and response sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Node.js is just a JS framework with a system API. Technically, you could reimplement Apache HTTP Server in Node.js, mimicking its behaviour and its configuration structure. But would you?

I believe you are using Node.js' [`HTTP`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) module. Look at the docs: there's no way to read configuration from a file. The server is programmatically created using `http.createServer`. You provide a callback that listens to requests. This callback provides an `http.IncomingMessage` parameter (first parameter) which contains everything you need.

Here's an example:

```
// load the module
var http = require('http');

// create the HTTP server
var server = http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  // use the "request" object to know everything about the request
  console.log('got request!');

  // method ('GET', 'POST', 'PUT, etc.):
  console.log('HTTP method: ' + request.method);

  // URL:
  console.log('HTTP URL: ' + request.url);

  // headers:
  console.log('HTTP headers follow:');
  console.log(request.headers);

  // client address:
  console.log('client address: ' + request.socket.address().address);
});

// listen on port 8000
server.listen(8000);
```

If you really want a configuration file, you will have to forge it yourself. I suggest creating a JSON configuration file as this can be turned directly into a JS object using `JSON.parse()`. Then just use your configuration object programmatically to achieve what you want.

Comment: so basically... the http model doesn't have configuration of its own.  I should use the callback from the create server method and do checks in there.

Comment: so basically... if I want to make sure the incoming request side is not larger than say 2k... I need to check the size in the callback function..

Comment: Yes. Read the request and get its size.